# How to use from import if I would like to import the module as a String?

Tags: python, arrays, import, module

I have a list of module names in an array.
I would like to import all these modules from an already imported class. 
It seems like I can't use **from TestModule __import__(name)**

How can I do that? Here is what I have:

```
import MainModule
arr = \
    ['Module1', 'Module2', 'Module3', 'Module4', 'Module5']
for string in arr:
     # Use FROM  to import the sub classes somehow
     from MainModule __import__(string)
```

Of course Python won't allow me to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import MainModule
arr = \
    ['Module1', 'Module2', 'Module3', 'Module4', 'Module5']
for string in arr:
    globals()[string] = getattr(MainModule, string)
```

might help you, although modifying `globals()` is not very elegant.

Better

```
modules = {string: getattr(MainModule, string) for string in arr}
```

and then do with `modules` whatever you want, e. g.

```
class MyModulesHolder(dict):
    pass

modules = MyModulesHolder()
modules.__dict__ = modules
modules.update({string: getattr(MainModule, string) for string in arr})
```

so that you can do `modules.Module2.whatever()`.

Comment: Cheers glglgl. That worked.